# Google OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications server side java

Tags: java, oauth, google-api

I am trying to implement Google APIs for Shopping Content. To access the APIs need to pass OAuth authentication.

Check the link
[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

In this guide, OAuth needs user consent for allowing the access. Check Step 3

"Google prompts user for consent" on server side"

I want to perform this step server side, is there any way for doing this in java?

Comment: Yes please read the tutorial in this link http://tutorials.jenkov.com/oauth2/index.html

Comment: Try using a service account https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/how-tos/service-accounts

Comment: @VishnuKR how is that going to help it has nothing to do with Google API?  It is not even remotely useful to this question.

Comment: That is explaining how oauth2 is working . The base knowledge I thought that will help you.